# How to modify time interval in altair line graph

Tags: python, altair

I have a simple line graph that looks like this: [line graph of stock returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA0Vm.png)

I have been trying to format the x axis such that the time interval is in years instead of months, as it currently is now. But when I use the timeUnit attribute, it produces a stunted graph like this: [line graph of stock returns in years](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7bP9.png)

Code:

```
alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x = alt.X('Date', timeUnit = 'year'),
    y = alt.Y('Cumul_R', axis = alt.Axis(format='%', orient='right')),

    color = 'Stock')
```

What I'm trying to produce is a graph that looks like the first graph, but with intervals expressed in years like 06-2010, 06-2011, ... etc without compressing the graph like in the second pic. In other words, how do I only show some tick labels and not all of them.

I've seen answers to my question but they deal with absolute values using tickCount or tickMinStep, not for datetime values. There is apparently an altair attribute called timeinterval in [https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.TimeInterval.html#altair.TimeInterval.**init**](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.TimeInterval.html#altair.TimeInterval.__init__)
that may solve the problem, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Appreciate all help on the matter. Thank you!

Comment: Please include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, the answer to your question will depend on how your data is formatted, so without that information it will be difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are plotting your dates as *nominal* typed values, when you should probably be plotting them as *temporal*.

You should change `x = alt.X('Date')` to `x = alt.X('Date:T')` to specify that the x channel is temporal. When you do that, the renderer will use a temporal axis label that is probably closer to what you had in mind.

See [Encoding Data Types](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encoding.html#encoding-data-types) in the documentation for more information.